# How to get face detection information from Panasonic smartHD camera embedded in video stream?

Tags: camera, face-detection

I've got a Panasonic WV SP-306 digital camera. It has a built-in function for face detection, and the information can be sent via xml notifications or embedded in the video stream. I'm trying to figure out how to get this information from mjpeg stream.

My discoveries so far:

I've found official documentation and SDK [here](http://panasonic.net/pss/security/library/developer.html)

There's a PDF document describing the jpeg header format ([Panasonic Camera JPEG Format](http://ssbu-t.psn-web.net/For_developer/IP_camera/English/Panasonic_Camera_JPEG_Format_V1.00.pdf) )
According to the document, the header of jpeg after `FF FE` bytes and the two length bytes consists of sections. Each section has 2-byte ID followed by 2 bytes indicating length. Then goes the body of the section. There're three sections described in the document: section with ID 0010 (related to motion detection), `ID 0011` (time information) and `ID 0012` (frame information, it has something about the time of the frame, not sure what it is for).

When I turn on the face detection feature, the fourth section appears. It has ID 000F and is not described in the documentation.

The sample programs and library reference were not useful, too. All I can do with face detection is turn it on or off and set the color of the face detection rectangle. I think all the processing of face detection data in the stream is done by the library.

So, my question is: can anybody tell me how to get the face detection data provided by this camera from the stream?